# Unable to find akka Configurations with Spark Submit

Tags: scala, akka, spark-submit, alpakka

I built a fat jar and I am trying to run it with spark-submit on an EMR or locally. here is the command:

```
spark-submit \
--deploy-mode client  \
--class com.stash.data.omni.source.Runner myJar.jar  \
<arguments>
```

I keep getting an error related to akka configurations:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
```

It seems like the jar cannot find the `reference.conf`s for akka at all. Has anyone dealt with this? I am able to run it without spark-submit on my local machine.

Comment: Can you describe exactly how are you building your jar?

Comment: Are you using maven or sbt to build jar?

Comment: im using sbt assembly to build my jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my merge strategy. i had a catch all `case _ => MergeStrategy.first`. i changed it to `case x => MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(x)` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is bundling into a jar with all it's dependencies, which causes problems with Akka, as described in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#when-using-jarjar-onejar-assembly-or-any-jar-bundler):

> Akka’s configuration approach relies heavily on the notion of every
>   module/jar having its own reference.conf file. All of these will be
>   discovered by the configuration and loaded. Unfortunately this also
>   means that if you put/merge multiple jars into the same jar, you need
>   to merge all the reference.conf files as well: otherwise all defaults
>   will be lost.

You can follow this [documentation](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/snapshot/additional/packaging.html#sbt-native-packager) to package your application and process to merge the `reference.conf` resources while bundling.It talks about packaging using sbt, maven, and gradle.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: i had `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.5")` still throws the error